# How to read a part of an XML as an XML in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: xml, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, xquery

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2 and my stored procedure takes in a structured XML which has multiple levels like this:

```
DECLARE @XML xml = 
'<Main>
    <User id="1">
        <Departments isSingle="0">
            <Department id="1">Admin</Department>
            <Department id="2">HR</Department>
            <Department id="3">Development</Department>
        </Departments>
    </User>
    <User id="2">
        <Departments isSingle="1">
            <Department id="1">Admin</Department>            
        </Departments>
    </User>
</Main>'
```

From the above example I want to get 2 columns for Users with multiple departments (isSingle="0") where first column is the user id and second column is the whole `<Departments>` XML.

I can get the user id with the following query but how to get the Departments section as an XML:

```
SELECT
      T.C.value('(../@id)','int') AS UserID
    , T.C.value('(../Departments)[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS DepartmentsXML 
FROM 
@XML.nodes('/Main/User/Departments[@isSingle="0"]') AS T(C)
```

It does not allow me to use `xml` as datatype in place of `nvarchar(max)`

If details are not clear let me know and I will try to refine it. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You want to obtain the whole `Departments` node as-is from the XML, not the Department ID and name values for each?

Comment: @DarthContinent Yes i want the Departments XML node itself

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're close - just use `.query('.')` for your second column:

```
SELECT
      T.C.value('(../@id)','int') AS UserID, 
      T.C.query('.') AS DepartmentsXML 
FROM 
@XML.nodes('/Main/User/Departments[@isSingle="0"]') AS T(C)
```

This will return the XML fragment as selected by the `.nodes()` call, as an XML.